# Extra backslash before every double quote when getting data cols from df and storing it in another df in a single column using "struct" function

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a pyspark dataframe in which there are many columns like **ID, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4**. Each of these column has string data in which is like this

```
ID = 123
Col1 = 1
Col2 = {"value": [-123.456, 789.123], "type": "abc"}
Col3 = [["value", [-123.456, 789.123]], ["type", "abc"]]
Col4 = [{"value": {"va1" : -123.456, "va2" : 789.123}, "type": ["abc", "def"]}, {"va1" : -123.456, "va2" : 789.123}, "type": ["abc", "def"]}]
```

The value in Col2, Col3, Col4 is of string data type.
I want to add all of these columns in a single column like a dictionary, where key would be Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 and they would have a corresponding value as their value.

I am doing this

```
new_df = old_df.withColumn("TF", struct(col(Col1), col(Col2), col(Col3)))
```

The new df is coming like:

```
TF: {
Col1 : 1
Col2 : {\"value\": [-123.456, 789.123], \"type\": \"abc\"}
Col3 = [[\"value\", [-123.456, 789.123]], [\"type\", \"abc\"]]
Col4 = [{\"value\": {\"va1\" : -123.456, \"va2\" : 789.123}, \"type\": [\"abc\", \"def\"]}, {\"va1\" : -123.456, \"va2\" : 789.123}, \"type\": [\"abc\", \"def\"]}]
}
```

I don't want the backslash character.
I just want the following:

```
TF: {
Col1 : 1
Col2 : {"value": [-123.456, 789.123], "type": "abc"}
Col3 = [["value", [-123.456, 789.123]], ["type", "abc"]]
Col4 = [{"value": {"va1" : -123.456, "va2" : 789.123}, "type": ["abc", "def"]}, {"va1" : -123.456, "va2" : 789.123}, "type": ["abc", "def"]}]
}
```

I have tried regex but it is not working.
How do I remove the backslashes from the data? I have to upload this data to CosmosDB. In CosmosDB it is showing backslash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried an example using pyspark:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, struct, regexp_replace, from_json
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructType
data = [(123, 1, '{"value": [-123.456, 789.123], "type": "abc"}')]
columns = ['ID', 'Col1', 'Col2']
old_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
print("Old DataFrame:")
old_df.show(truncate=False)
old_df = old_df.withColumn("Col2", regexp_replace(col("Col2"), "\\\\", ""))
schema = StructType().add("value", StringType()).add("type", StringType())
old_df = old_df.withColumn("Col2", from_json(col("Col2"), schema))
new_df = old_df.withColumn("TF", struct(col("Col1"), col("Col2")))
print("New DataFrame:")
new_df.display(truncate=False)
```

**Results:**

```
| ID  | Col1 | Col2                                           |
|-----|------|------------------------------------------------|
| 123 | 1    | {"value": "[-123.456,789.123]", "type": "abc"} |
```

```
| ID  | Col1 | Col2                                           | TF                                                                  |
|-----|------|------------------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 123 | 1    | {"value": "[-123.456,789.123]", "type": "abc"} | {"Col1": 1, "Col2": {"value": "[-123.456,789.123]", "type": "abc"}} |
```

- You can use the  `regexp_replace`  function to eliminate the
  backslashes from the string in the ‘**Col2**’ column. This function is designed to substitute occurrences of a particular regular expression (in this case, backslashes) in the specified column with an empty string.
  By doing this, you can effectively remove all backslashes from the ‘**Col2**’ column.
- Defining a schema named ‘**schema**’ with the  `StructType`  class, you can specify the structure for the nested data. This schema should include two fields, namely ‘`value`’ and ‘`type`’, both of which should be of type  `StringType`. This way, you can create a structuredblueprint for organizing and handling data that contains these specific fields and types.
- parse the  **JSON**  string in the ‘**Col2**’ column according to the predefined schema, you can use the ‘`from_json`’ function. This function is specifically designed to convert the  **JSON**  string into a structured format that adheres to the specified schema. By using this function, you can effectively transform the  **JSON**  string into a more organized and easily manipulable format based on the predefined schema.
- You can add a new column named ‘**TF**’ to the DataFrame '**old_df**’by using the ‘`withColumn`’ method. This new column, ‘**TF**’, can be created as a structure containing ‘**Col1**’ and the modified ‘**Col2**’, where ‘**Col2**’ has been parsed according to the previously defined schema. By employing this method, you can effectively integrate the structured data from ‘**Col1**’ and the transformed ‘**Col2**’ into the new column ‘**TF**’ within the DataFrame.